# Symfony Bundle for OpenAPI Schema Separation

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, openapi

Which Symfony Bundle to use if I want to keep the OpenAPI schema separate from the controllers? Ideally, I would like to have the OpenAPI schema for the controllers in a .yaml config and then generate the API doc based on that.

I tried:

[NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) - however this one is very limiting and failed to separate the OpenAPI schema from the controllers.

[nijens/openapi-bundle](https://github.com/nijens/openapi-bundle) - This one looks like it can do what I need. But it is little used.

What would you use for this purpose? Do you know of any better bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/php-symfony).  This uses an openapi yaml or json file to generate your symfony controllers and models.  I personally haven't used it for symfony, but I have used it for many other languages.  The tool is robust and does exactly what you are asking.  It uses mustache template to generate classes.  Checking the available templates for `php-symfony`, the generator has a [controller template](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/php-symfony/Controller.mustache) and a separate [model template](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/php-symfony/model.mustache).  This means it will keep your model definitions separate from your controller, which seems to be what you are looking for.